# Implementing connected component labeling for 8-connectivity using c++ for matrices as large as 1000 x 1000

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graphics, matrix

How to implement CCL in c++ for a binary matrix of large size ? I have checked the algorithm in Wikipedia but I cannot understand how to go about solving it and also implementing the data structure to store the equivalance !! Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I was trying to write pseudocode for the algorithm and I use one extra matrix for labelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mark all nodes unassigned.

Iterate through all nodes:
    If node unassigned:
        Assign node to a new component id C
        Do a depth-first-search for all nodes connected to this one:
             mark them with same component id C
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Should I use an array to mark all the nodes initially ??

Comment: yes.  Create an array of int the same size as matrix.  0 initialize means unassigned.  Start counting components from 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Ill work out the problem as you said.Will update soon here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using graphs, exploit a union-find data structure (also called disjoint-set data-strucutre)